# delete sample products in Magento 2 but maintaining sample categories and luma layout

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to delete the sample products, orders, customers and invoices but maintain the categories and also the layout. I'm using Magento 2.
Any way to do that easily or should I just delete them one by one?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score -1):

**For delete sample product**

Login to Admin, then go to

Product -> Catalog

select **check box** of the product, then click the **action drop down** then click **delete**.

if you want to delete all, select all and then delete

**For delete Customers**

Customers->All Customers

select all customer then delete

**For delete order&invoice**

The Default Magento only allows changing order status into cancel for any completed order or test order without deleting.

use magento 2 exetnsion, if you want delete order

for example
https://www.magecheckout.com/magento-2-delete-order-extension.html

have a good luck